# How to add domain to hosting?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I created a hosting (free) and register a free domain at another site. How to configure it to work site. Hosting says:

> Please change the DNS of your domain to the following and allow 24-48 hours for the DNS update:
>   dns1.freehostia.com
>   dns2.freehostia.com

But at domain site I have three fields:

1. HOST
2. Type(A, CNAME)
3. IPv4

Comment: Look for your nameserver settings at your domain registrar.

Comment: At domain registrator i have only three fields
http://pix.am/CGob/

Comment: If they don't let you change the nameservers, then you can only assume you must also host with them. If they say you can host with other providers then somewhere you can change the nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

I case the you use freehostia you can add an A record to your domain and use the IP address of the server your site is hosted on. You can find the IP address here:

[image]